# Copying multi char array to another multi char array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, memcpy

I'm converting Java code to C, and something as simple as swapping contents of multi arrays in Java:

```
boolean[][] temp = board;
board = nextBoard;
nextBoard = temp;
```

Seems to be a lot more troublesome in C.

After viewing similar questions on this site, I have learned that I have to use `memcpy` which I initiated in a method called `arrayCopy`.

This is `arrayCopy`:

```
 void arrayCopy(char * a, char * b)
 {
     struct universe data;
     int r;
     for(r = 0; r < data.rows; r++)
     memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a));
 }
```

Which I call from the main method:

```
char temp[SIZE][SIZE];
arrayCopy(&data.board, &temp);
arrayCopy(&data.nextBoard, &data.board);
arrayCopy(&temp, &data.nextBoard);
```

With the following struct:

```
struct universe
{
  char board[SIZE][SIZE];
  char nextBoard[SIZE][SIZE];
  int columns;
  int rows;
}universe;
```

But I'm getting warnings such as:

> A2Q1.c:189:15: warning: incompatible pointer types passing
>         'char (*)[60][60]' to parameter of type 'char *'

Yet `memcpy` only returns pointers, so I can't switch the parameters. I also can't use `malloc()` yet as other questions suggest because I have not learned it yet, so any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What's data.rows supposed to contain? You never initialize that struct at all - that loop will probably make your program segfault. sizeof(a) is also wrong, it will return the size of a pointer, and not SIZE.

Comment: I initialize it in another part of the program, it reads in the number of rows from an input file.

Comment: Is that function the same in the other part of your program? Because if it is, that's still wrong.

Comment: `board[SIZE][SIZE]` is a pointer, there is no need to take its address when passed as an argument. *(i.e.: `(&data.board, &temp)` should be `(data.board, temp)`) Additionally when passing statically declared arrays, it is always necessary to pass the number of elements in each row (i.e. `arrayCopy(char * a, char * b)` will need to be `arrayCopy(char a[][SIZE], char b[][SIZE])`). You can see what the compiler is complaining about in the `'char (*)[60][60]'`part of the error message.

Comment: Further, `sizeof(a)` is meaningless in your `arrayCopy` function (well, not meaningless -- it just reports the size of the character pointer `a` which is always `8` on 64-bit boxes and `4` on x86 boxes. Why? pointer decay.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `sizeof(a)` definitely is giving me errors, is there a way to fix that? Should I use `strlength()` or something?

Comment: Yes, pass the `sizeof` your arrays as an argument to your function. The `sizeof` in `main()` (or wherever the arrays are declared) will contain the number of bytes in the array. Once passed as an argument, then the array decays to a simple pointer and `sizeof` then just gives pointer size. (or pass the whole struct so the compiler knows the size of the arrays at issue -- See BLUEPIXY's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
void swapBoard(struct universe *x){
    char temp[SIZE][SIZE];
    memcpy(temp, x->board, sizeof(temp));
    memcpy(x->board, x->nextBoard, sizeof(temp));
    memcpy(x->nextBoard, temp, sizeof(temp));
}
int main(){
    struct universe data;
    //...
    swapBoard(&data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it a bit over-complicated. You can use memcpy directly in your example above to copy everything from a to b without iterating through it. If you run this code...

```
int main()
{
    char temp[60][60];
    printf("%d", sizeof(temp));
}
```

You'll see that sizeof will give you 3600 bytes, 60*60 to the total bytes allocated by the array. These byte are allocated in a contiguous chunk of memory and memcpy can copy them in one swoop. This demonstrates the point:

```
int main()
{
    char temp[60][60];
    memset(temp, 'a', sizeof(temp));
    char temp2[60][60];
    memset(temp2, 'b', sizeof(temp2));
    memcpy(temp2, temp, sizeof(temp2));
    printf("%c", temp2[23][34]);
}
```

The printf will print 'a'. In your code above, this should work just fine:

```
char temp[SIZE][SIZE];
memcpy(data.board, temp, sizeof(data.board));
memcpy(data.nextBoard, data.board, sizeof(data.nextBoard));
memcpy(temp, data.nextBoard, sizeof(temp));
```

Note that this assumes all of these arrays are identical in size. You may want to create a minsize function or use a macro function like `#define MINSIZE(a,b) (sizeof((a)) < sizeof((b)) ? sizeof((a)) : sizeof((b)))` to be safe.